# Prove that matrices with property commute

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

We have $XY = \lambda X + \mu Y$, both coefficients $\lambda, \mu \neq 0$, prove that $X$ and $Y$ commute. $X$ and $Y$ are square matrices

Ok, it's simple. Can you tell me why my approach is wrong?

$X=\frac{1}{\lambda}(XY-\mu Y)$, same for Y. Then I calculate YX, and with some work and simplification I get YX=XY. Why is this approach is wrong?

Why this is not a proof?

$YX= \frac{1}{\lambda \mu}[(XY)^2 - \mu XY^2 - \lambda X^2Y + \lambda \mu XY]$

$=\frac{1}{\lambda \mu}[(XY)^2 - X(\mu Y + \lambda X)Y + \lambda \mu XY]$

$=XY$

Comment: Why do you think your approach is wrong?

Comment: It was in intro exam and I got -+ for it, but I was thinking its simple and very frustrated right now;-(

Comment: @user26857 $X=\frac{1}{\lambda}(XY-\mu Y)$ and $Y=\frac{1}{\mu}(XY-\lambda X)$, then plug it into YX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $(X-\mu I)(Y- \lambda I) = \lambda \mu I$.

Comment: Can you look up at the second question please?

Comment: Why $\det(X - \mu I) \neq 0$ or $\det(Y - \lambda I) \neq 0$ ?

Comment: @Paravozik : Because the question assumes $\lambda \mu \neq 0.$ I guess you do need to assume matrices have entries in a ring without zero divisors.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson But $\lambda, \mu$ can be eigenvalues of matrices $X$ and $Y$. So, we will have zero determinant, right?

Comment: But the question tells us that we have numbers $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that $XY = \lambda X + \mu Y$. They are not arbitrary numbers. We are also told that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are non-zero. Assuming they are in a field, which I think the question intends, then $\lambda \mu \neq 0$.Then add $\lambda \mu I $ to both sides of the equation $XY - \lambda X - \mu Y = 0$ to get the equation I gave in the answer above.